# Load and save NSMutableArray won't work

Tags: objective-c, ios, file

first of all, I have a class which mamages an NSMutableArray.
When the class is instantiated, it should look if there is already a saved array and load it, or otherwise made a new one.

everytime an item is added it should be saved. but: nothing happens.

```
#import "NEList.h"

@interface NEList()



@end

@implementation NEList
@synthesize theInternArray;



-(id) initWithArray {
    self = [super init];

    if(self != nil) {
             NSLog(@"build");

        theInternArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];

        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(id) initWithContent {
    self = [super init];

    if(self != nil) {
        NSLog(@"load");

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"theFiles"];

        theInternArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        if(theInternArray == nil) {
            theInternArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:200];
        }
               NSLog(@"second %@", theInternArray);
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(BOOL) save {

   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"theFiles"];


    return [self.theInternArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
}

-(BOOL) addObject:(NEListItem *)theItem {

    [theInternArray addObject:theItem];    [self save];





    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotif.fireDate = theItem.theBestBeforeDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotif.alertBody = [theItem.theName stringByAppendingString:@" expires!"];
    localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View Details", nil);

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;



    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];


    return true;
}


-(NEListItem *) getElementAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex {
    return [theInternArray objectAtIndex:theIndex];
}

-(BOOL)removeObjectByName:(NSString *)theName {

    for (NEListItem *tempItem in theInternArray) {

        if([tempItem.theName isEqualToString:theName]) {
            [theInternArray removeObject:tempItem];
            break;
            return true;
            }
    }

            NSLog(@"Nicht gefunden");
            return false;
        }






@end
```

the save method is called in another class which owns an instance of NEList

Comment: Have you tried using NSUserDefaults instead of saving it as a file? Also, how are you instantiating the Array upon launch?

Comment: The Array is the data source for a TableView. in the TableView viewDidLoad    self.theDataList  = [[NEList alloc] initWithContent]; is called. theDataList is a NEList

Comment: Yeah, you should defiantly use NSUserDefaults for this (it's less complicated, takes less space, just a better experience). Do you know how to use it?

Comment: nah, this is my first iphone app attempt :) there are a few objetcs of NEItem which are stored in a NSMutableArray and diplayed in a table view. got to look at the UserDefaults, but this sounds more like an options file?

Comment: Here give a minute and I'll just convert your methods to use NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, all I changed was the "initWithContent" Method and the save method. I've commented out your code and under it made the changes to use NSUserDefaults. NSUserDefaults should save a binary file of your Array and later get it back and convert it back to a NSArray. If this doesn't work just let me know what error your getting.

```
-(id) initWithContent {
    self = [super init];

    if(self != nil) {
        NSLog(@"load");
        /*
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"theFiles"];

        theInternArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        if(theInternArray == nil) {
            theInternArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:200];
        }
        NSLog(@"second %@", theInternArray);*/
        NSUserDefaults *uDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        theInternArray = [uDefaults objectForKey:@"internArray"];
        if (!theInternArray)
        {
            theInternArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:200];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", theInternArray);

        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(BOOL) save {

    /*NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"theFiles"];*/

    NSUserDefaults *uDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [uDefaults setObject:theInternArray forKey:@"internArray"];


    //return [self.theInternArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
    return [uDefaults objectForKey:@"internArray"];
}
```

Oh, and the reason why your way didn't work is because it's not that simple to save a file then get it back. You would need to print out your data from the array (like "item1,item2,item3, etc." to the file, then parse it and create a NSArray with that data later.

Comment: thank you for your effort; but this gives me an error Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.

Comment: Haha yes sorry about that it's standardUserDefaults not shared :)

Comment: thanks, edited wrong above: this gives me Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.

Comment: What objects are being stored into the array?

Comment: interface NEListItem : NSObject

property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *theName;
property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *theBestBeforeDate;
property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *theInternDate;


-(id) initWithName:(NSString *) theInitName;
 those

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15739/discussion-between-manox-and-ablx)

Comment: @ABLX no problem, if that code that I gave you in chat didn't work, I have no idea what else to do. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is the solution worked for me. 
First of all, this is my custom class which is stored in the arrays:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NEListItem : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *theName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *theBestBeforeDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *theInternDate;


-(id) initWithName:(NSString *) theInitName;
 @end
```

and the implementation

```
#import "NEListItem.h"

@implementation NEListItem
@synthesize theName = _theName;
@synthesize theBestBeforeDate = _theBestBeforeDate;
@synthesize theInternDate = _theInternDate;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)theInitName {
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil) {
        self.theName = theInitName;

        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    [coder encodeObject:self.theName forKey:@"theName"];
    [coder encodeObject:self.theBestBeforeDate forKey:@"theBBDate"];
    [coder encodeObject:self.theInternDate forKey:@"theInternDate"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    self = [[NEListItem alloc] init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.theName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"theName"];
        self.theInternDate = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"theInternDate"];
        self.theBestBeforeDate = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"theBBDate"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

so, this is needed for saving custom values.

the save method:

```
-(BOOL) save {

    NSLog(@"save called");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:theInternArray] forKey:@"savedArray"];
    return true;
    }
```

and the loading which is part of a init method

```
 NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"savedArray"];


            NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];

        if (oldSavedArray != nil) {
                theInternArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
            return self;
        }
            else
                          theInternArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:200];
        return self;
        }
```

many thanks to ManOx which helped me a lot